# Makefile equivalent for maven

Tags: maven, makefile, pom.xml

When I compile projects, in a C/Makefile project I can simply open the makefile and see the targets. Then do:

```
make TARGET
```

When I open a pom.xml file, it's somewhat unclear how to test/run/deploy projects. It's sort of a work of art at times, where I have to dig around documentation, try stuff etc.. I.e, it's not clear what the project designer had in mind right away.

Considering I'm new-ish to maven, can someone explain how to find the most likely goals of a pom.xml file given a new project?

[edit]
I understand there are defined life-cycle goals, but I find these generally don't cover edge cases. (e.g custom paramaters, or I have to figure out how to run with particular profile etc... i.e, it's not quick/straight forward, I still have to review documentation usually).

Comment: The is not such thing as a `target`. You have a life cycle which can done everything you need. You can call `mvn clean` or you can call `mvn package` and that will never change. You never need to look into the pom.xml to know the existing life cycle phases ... see Docs https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: No, well, for example an author may want me to run "mvn clean package -Pjboss-managed -DfailIfNoTests=false", which is not covered by common life-cycle.. Or for example something that doesn't quite fit the standard life cycles.

Comment: Usually I say a maven build which uses a profile has a smell...and in particular if we start to talk about existing/ignoring tests. Furthermore the profile and the system properties are options to go into more fine controlling things within the life cycle which is usually a bad idea but sometimes you can't prevent it.Apart from that it looks like that I misunderstand you question? If you give someone without knowledge of a Makefile a Makefile to read he needs to read the docs first before understand what a target is or what phony targets are etc. ?

Comment: A _good_ `pom.xml` should be written in a way that you can just call `mvn clean package`. I know that this is not always possible, but that is what you should aim for.

Comment: @khmarbaise Well, sometimes different profiles are used if you want to deploy to different places. E.g local javaEE server or a docker based one in the cloud. A single life cycle won't work and then it's not clear how to use that profile or which args it would take.
A makefile is very easy to read and the targets are auto-completed from terminal, which is certainly not the case for pom.xml files.

Comment: @JFMeier Well, that's kinda the theory of pom.xml files. But in real life I keep running into pom.xml files that need to be ran in a particular way and it's not easy to tell how by looking at only the pom.xml file.

Comment: If you deploy to a Server with Maven(JavaEE etc.) then you are doing wrong. Maven is not intended to do deployments to servers. Only the artifacts into an artifact repository (repository manager like Nexus/Artifactory/Archiva). Maven is a build tool not a deployment tool. Working with an EE server locally I have my IDE to do that while development /Spring Boot running locally via IDE / to the cloud there exist solutions like https://heroku.com/ just to mentioned one... or use Jenkins to do deployments on environments.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes that should generally be the case for production code. But often quick start projects or sample projects do all sorts of things with pom.xml and figuring out how to use those is not trivial I found.

Comment: In particular quickstarts or sample projects should really do it right which is exactly what I requested to keep things to the tool which is used and not to try  things which do not belong there which makes it harder to understand as you realized.

Comment: @khmarbaise There are a lot of corner cases that simply can't be done in the ideal world. E.g a pom.xml file may use the version plugin to print which dependencies need updated. Or e.g a migration plugin which may advise which plugins to replace. Or other maintenance tasks that normally woudn't be part of the regular build cycle. You name it. Suggesting that everything should be one in an ideal but not real-life way is not very useful.

Comment: You can simply configure the version for versions-maven-plugin to show the dependencies updated via `mvn versions:display-update-report` without any issues that is simple without any problem. The real life shows me over the last 12 years+ with Maven the more tasks are tried to be done within the pom the less the build is maintainable ...the more conditions are in the pom the more it becomes unmaintainable...thats real life experience not ideal world...and focusing on the primary things the tool is intended for...would be the same as using a Makefile for Compiling/Building Java EE application

Comment: Well again, you need to know about 'versions:display-....-report', its not clear how to find that goal or what the person had in mind when he added the dependency to the project. I don't need more tasks done in the pom, I need to be able to read the existing items. I'm not asking a philosophical question about best way of managing things. I'm simply trying to understand how do I find out the intended goals of the pom.xml that the designer/architect had in mind. How do you normally find the goals of a pom.xml when you look at it for the first time? Do you just assume "mvn package" always works?

Comment: The assumption is yes that `mvn package` or `mvn test` or `mvn verify` always works cause otherwise that project is simply wrong. Special things are usually documented in a README (using some special profiles for doing special things?)  or if I really need to I will look into the pom file...but usually this is becoming rare over the time...

Comment: Thank you. It's useful to hear someone's life experience. Although it does show that for special cases one has to check the README. I'd prefer code/configuration to be self-documenting, e.g expose 'special' goals/configs explicitly somehow such that they'd popup in tab-completion in the 'mvn ...' command line.. This could also be used in tooling (e.g Eclipse IDE) so that tools can show relevant context menues. Hmm. I wonder if there is a plugin for that.